# Discord.py How can I Delete All Roles İn Server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to do "new server" command and it is perfectly working. İt delete all channels and categories with this code

```
 for c in ctx.guild.channels:
        await c.delete()
    for category in ctx.guild.categories:
        await category.delete()
```

After that my bot cretaes roles and and channels etc. But I couldn't figure out how to delete all roles. I would be very happy if somone help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
for role in ctx.guild.roles:
    role.delete()
```

This should work completely fine

I hope I helped!

Let me know if it worked or not

Comment: There is no error in terminal but  not worked @Emir Sürmen

Comment: discord.Role.delete is a coroutine method and you need to await it @Mehmet_faik

Comment: ı know, ı await but still didn't work @NerdGuyAhmad

Comment: Can you send full code please? Use some kind of bin to upload the code